# Are there assembly instructions which both read from, and write to, memory?

Tags: assembly, x86, arm, memory, mips

Is it a safe assumption, say for x86, that an instruction either does not access memory, or only reads from memory, or writes to memory?

I could not find any instruction but I am not sure if this really is the case.

What about ARM and MIPS?

Comment: `movsb` has been in the x86 family since the venerable 8086 and reads and writes memory.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the counter example. This means I have to deal with the case.

Comment: You'll also have to deal with all instructions where the combined source/destination operand can be a memory location, starting with the lowly `inc [mem]` and `add [mem], whatever`.

Comment: On ARM there only instructions that touch memory is "read from memory to a register" and "write a register to memory, so no.

Comment: In addition to `movsb`, there's also [`bts`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_25.html).

Comment: really, there are lots on x86: add, adc, sbb, and, sub, xor, xchg, cmpxchg, , shl, shr, rol, rcl, rcr, ror, sar, neg, not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has been answered in comments for x86 - `movsb` both reads and writes to memory.

On ARM the only instructions that touch memory is "read from memory to a register" and "write a register to memory", so no there aren't. Same with MIPS.

IIRC all (or almost all?) RISC processors are this "load and store" architecture.